# Throwing appropriate exceptions and message for Spring JMX Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-jmx

I have a MBean that throws a runtime exception to the effect

```
Error during MBean operation invocationMessage: RuntimeException thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation someMethod
```

Is there a way I can coax the exception to display a more informative message to the JMX MBean Management Console

Answer (score 0):

Which console?

In both `VisualVM` and `JConsole`, I get

> Problem invoking fooBar: java.lang.RuntimeException: foo

where `foo` is the exception's `message` property.

Comment: That's no help at all - what app server? i.e. what is listening on 8080?

Comment: its listening on a custom port 37071 and on tomcat

Comment: But what do you have deployed on tomcat in `/mbean` servlet path? You must have some war file deployed there; AFAIR, tomcat doesn't come with a web-based mbean console. It's that code that you need to fix to provide more information about the exception.